How to structure a complex inventory system in Unity?
My inventory needs to deal with different Item types. Item is my base class, which is extended by Armor, Weapon, Spell, Scroll and I might add more in the future.
All items have an interaction on right click.
Armor and Weapon are equipped.
Spell is put in the spellbook.
Scroll is activated and you can left click an Armor or Weapon Item to upgrade it.
All items can also be dragged.
All items can be dragged between inventory slots. They can be dragged to a new empty slot, or on top of an existing item which will swap their inventory slots.
Armor and Weapon can be dragged to Equipment and will be equipped there. They can also be dragged from Equipment to Inventory and be unequipped.
Spells can be dragged between Inventory and Spellbook.
All items can be sold, but only while in Inventory.
Items are created (generated) during combat and saved on a server.
When the game loads all items need to be loaded from the server and put in their correct inventory slot or equipment/spellbook slot.
My current implementation is working, but it's way too complex and spread out.
I'm creating items in my Combat script and in my Inventory script.
EventManager is handling the dragging of items.
Inventory is handling the clicking of items.
Each Item type has it's own implementation of Equip/Unequip which calls different functions, ...
I'm not looking for someone to write out the code for me.
I just need some guidance on how to structure all of this.
Do I use the event system for everything?
Do I just make one function for each action? CreateItem, DragItem, DropItem, ClickItem, EquipItem, UnEquipItem, AddItemToSpellBook, RemoveItemFromSpellbook, ...
This sounds simple, but the code gets so complex so quickly.
I'm constantly forgetting things everywhere and even now I don't remember exactly where to find everything.
For example each Item needs to track which InventorySlot it is in, so that on loading the Item it can be put back in the correct InventorySlot.
But also each InventorySlot needs to track which Item is in it, so that when I drag an Item on top of an InventorySlot that contains an Item, I know which Item is in that InventorySlot so I can swap them.
If I forget to set either one when equipping an item for example, it creates very weird bugs where suddenly multiple Items disappear or get moved.

So you ideally want to set the whole thing up as one InventoryManager gateway class, through which all inventory transactions are made. Start by planning it out the way you'd like it to be, and post that pseudocode here, then we can tell you if it's possible in Unity, and/or whether it makes sense. Otherwise we are just taking shots in the dark.

Why would the item need to keep track of the inventory slot? It sounds like something is wrong with the structure of your code there. The inventory slot should keep track of the item, but the item shouldn't know or care what inventory slot it's in.

It's an iterative process. That fact you're thinking of these things is progress. Sometimes, turn the thing around: instead of "Add Item", "object.AddMeToWhatever". Extend the object to localize available behaviour. (obj.RememberSlot; obj.FindSlot)

It is hard to give any practical advice from a broad description of the problem, but I assume that your system became complex and now it is hard to work with it because of the following issues:

classes became interconnected
classes do multiple things
it is unclear who should do what
it is unclear how to interact between classes

So I am addressing theses problems here.
You can look into MV* UI patterns. In short, they consist of View, Model and some intermediate class that's called differently for each of them (Controller, ViewModel, Presenter etc.), giving them the final letter(s). You may not need the full implementation, but it is best to at least split your View and your Model.
The structure can be like that:
// Model layer
class Inventory {}
// class Equipment {}
class Item {}
class ArmorItem : Item {}
class WeaponItem : Item {}

// View layer
class InventoryView : MonoBeahviour{}
class EquipmentView : MonoBeahviour{}
class ArmorItemView : MonoBeahviour{}
class WeaponItemView : MonoBeahviour {}

Invetory class knows its properties and the items it contains, e.g.:
class Inventory {
    readonly Item[] _items = new Item[16];
    public int SlotsCount => _items.Length;
    public int ItemsCount => _items.Where(item => item != null).Count();
    public void AddItem(int slot, Item item) {}
    public void RemoveItem(int slot, Item item) {}
}

it can also provide additional info: array of empty slots etc. It can provide serialization options to serialize/deserialize all the data it contains. But what it doesn't know is it's visual representation. This means, dragging etc, is done separately.
Equipment is a similar class with some stricter type checking. Or it can simply doesn't exist. Instead there could be a bool _isEquipped field in the Item class, which could be enough.
Item class is the base class for items. Ideally it only contains data and methods to get and set this data. It may know how to serialize itself, but it is probably best to trigger serialization from Inventory anyway.
InventoryView represents the visual state of inventory, e.g.
public class InventoryView : MonoBehaviour {
    public Label _itemsCount;

    public void SetInventory(Inventory inventory) { 
        _itemsCount.text = inventory.ItemsCount;
    }
}

this class is responsible for anything visual - displaying the current state, animations, dragging, getting user interactions etc. Ideally, it should only work with Inventory only, but can also work with Equipment or Items directly if needed. This will increase the complexity, so it is best to separate everything as much as possible.
In full MV* patterns, the middle layer is responsible for getting the necessary data from the model and offering it to the View. In other words, if Inventory needs a list of item names, handles equipment itself etc. It will only work with e.g. InventoryController that will provide data to it, while InventoryController will have access to Inventory, Equipment and all the Items (through Inventory methods or through public list - doesn't matter). Why it is good? Because View contains the logic of the visuals and Model contains the logic of the application. And Controller doesn't contain any logic except the logic of gathering the data. This makes every class handle one problem, which makes it easier to understand the code
EquipmentView, ArmorItemView, WeaponItemView - are clearly related to inventory. InventoryView can own these classes and interact with them. But it should not do their job. E.g. it can hide an item in the slot for dragging and spawn an intermediate one, but it should not animate each item etc.
In full MV* pattern Views can interact with one another via intermediate layer. So, a View calls a method of its corresponding Controller, this Controller calls a method of another Controller and that Controller invokes an event to which its View is subscribed.
Dragging example
A user clicks on an item in the inventory and holds the click. This is identified either by the ItemView (in which case it reports it to the InventoryView) or by InventoryView itself. The ItemView in the slot is hidden, and the one of the same size and shape is spawned above the InventoryView. The user drags it to somewhere and releases.InventoryView checks where the release happened. If this was over EquipmentView it can notify the EquipmentView (if it is implemented) to handle the case and respond back (so the item in the inventory can be removed or visually updated). If that was over an inventory slot, it moves the ItemView to the proper slot and calls RemoveSlot and AddSlot of Inventory with old and new slot ids respecively, if no action is implied - it simply sets the visuals back to the original slot.
Swapping example
Your case of inventory slot and an item in inventory slot knowing of each other is no more than an implementation detail. You should have this info only in one place and use it from there. Swapping the items in the above procedure is no more than taking a slot number of one slot and the other slot and simply swap items. The items shuold know nothing about the slot number, it's only InventoryView and Inventory doing their job of swapping the items. If the data is serialized and/or sent to server by the inventory, rather than by an item. It really depends on how you organize the system.
Server interaction
Let's say, we need to update the state on server. Who does that? It depends. E.g. if multiple players can use inventory together - than InventoryView should send RPCs, so the visuals are in sync. If not, only Inventory needs  requests when it is updated.
Who creates who
Views in Unity are MonoBehaviours, nothing special here. The rest can be implemented differently. Options are:

everything can be MonoBehaviours
a Manager that creates all the classes needed for the inventory
singletons, at least for model layer classes
dependency injection

How to call back
C# events is the most default way. If we have a Model class and a View class, the model can expose its methods to be called by View and C# events to which View can subscribe. This way, Model will know nothing about View in which case it simply can't have any presentation logic at all. So, logic becomes free from visuals.
There are other ways to interact between classes without direct references, with reactive extensions (UniRx or R3) being arguably the best and Unity's SendMessage being arguably the worst. But they all are based on either of two ideas: either a subscription, like C# events, or that someone else should handle the interaction.
